# How can I order the groups in a pandas GroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with 3 columns: Date, Concept and Value. I want to add a fourth column "Rank" that contains the order statistic of Value when grouped by Date. So for example, consider the following table:

| Date | Concept | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 30 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 25 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 17 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 31 |
| 2021-02-01 | C | 42 |

In this case, my final table should be this:

| Date | Concept | Value | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 20 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 30 | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 25 | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | 17 | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | 31 | 2 |
| 2021-02-01 | C | 42 | 3 |

Is there any elegant way to do it with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform` with `pd.Series.rank`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2021-01-01 ', 1: '2021-01-01 ', 2: '2021-01-01 ', 3: '2021-02-01 ', 4: '2021-02-01 ', 5: '2021-02-01 '}, 
                   'Concept ': {0: 'A ', 1: 'B ', 2: 'C ', 3: 'A ', 4: 'B ', 5: 'C '}, 
                   'Value': {0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 25, 3: 17, 4: 31, 5: 42}})

df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['Date'])['Value'].transform(pd.Series.rank)
```

```
          Date Concept   Value  Rank
0  2021-01-01        A      20     1
1  2021-01-01        B      30     3
2  2021-01-01        C      25     2
3  2021-02-01        A      17     1
4  2021-02-01        B      31     2
5  2021-02-01        C      42     3
```